# SOAP call to ASMX with Python SUDS

Tags: python, web-services, asmx, suds

I'm calling an ASMX WS with Python SUDS.  Have been working with the namespaces for hours and I'm sure that these are correct.  Looking for some SUDS experience to answer a question.

I can't update this Web Service without breaking other things.  Until now all clients have been .NET clients.  Before I create another service I'm wondering if .NET types are a problem for SUDS?  I'll explain.

The Service call has a signature similar to this:
TakeInResults(MyTypes.Results R, string TransKey, int site, string equipmentId, string operator)

SOAPUI has no trouble with this - the Results type in the signature is broken out and I can use SOAPUI to push results into this call.  In SUDS, though, the Results type is never populated when the ASMX is called.  The other parts of the signature have no problems.  TransKey, site, equipmentId, operator are *always* filled by SUDS correctly.  However, the Results type is always NULL after the call.

Now, I've checked (ten times or more) the namespaces - they are all correct.  So I'm asking the question - will I ever be able to fill that .NET-based type from SUDS?  Again, this isn't an issue with SOAPUI.  I've captured the packets in Fiddler and WireShark - there isn't anything "strange" going on.  The packets sent to the ASMX are correct and the WS is getting the submission from SUDS that is identical to the one from SOAPUI (except that the naming of the namespaces are different between the two products).

Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE - futzing with SOAPUI taught me something interesting about the ASMX Web Services deployed in the ASP.NET 4 Runtime.  Suds is using XML entities for the sub-document created in Python.  For example, one of the Properties for the R type (explained above) is ProductID.  We created this tag in a different Python class.  _Before_ submission by SUDS the class created the XML Element like so: 

<ns1:ProductID>unknown</ns1:ProductID>.

However, in Fiddler the submission from SUDS to the Web Service this was transformed to 

&lt;ns1&gt;ProductIDunknown&lt;/ns1:ProductID&gt;

Comment: UPDATE Cont.  I mangled the < and > above when adding this comment.  Sorry.  But the actual entities and tags are correct in SUDS.  The point is - the two are equivalent, but NOT seen identically to the ASMX web service.  If I use SOAPUI and convert all the XML entities to actual characters (as originally created), then the R is correctly populated.  So Entities are not liked by the ASMX web service.  Whether this means I have to abandon SUDS altogether for the Python workflow is not yet clear to me.

Does anyone have any thoughts?